# jackett pkg outdated. is it possible to manually install the latest update?

Tags: freebsd, truenas, packages

The pkg and port listed for Jackett on FreeBSD is Version v0.20.989 however, the most up to date version is v0.20.2189. This version difference is causing some of my trackers to fail and will not consistently work. Is there any way to manually update this to the latest version even if pkg does not have the latest version?

Comment: Does TrueNAS use official FreeBSD packages? If yes, I can look into updating the port.

Comment: I believe they do. Searching for the jackett port on the FreeBSD website shows the outdated version as well. 
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=jackett&stype=all

Answer (score 0):

I have [updated the port](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/commit/363e6b96b829f04c0b32c301bb63079361df52de) to the latest version. It might take a couple of days until the binary package hits `latest` channel of the official repo.

In future, don't hesitate to open a problem report on our [Bugzilla](https://bugs.freebsd.org/) or ask on the `freebsd-ports` mailing list.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much